# Django: AttributeError - 'unicode' object has no attribute 'status'

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am getting the following `AttributeError`:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://192.168.33.10.xip.io:8000/episodeclicktotweet/2/

Django Version: 1.9
Python Version: 2.7.6
Installed Applications:
('producer',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'registration',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'storages',
 'django_extensions',
 'randomslugfield',
 'adminsortable2',
 'crispy_forms',
 'charsleft_widget')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware')



Traceback:

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/vagrant/fullcast_project/producer/views/views.py" in dispatch
  97.         return super(ProductionRequiredMixin, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in dispatch
  88.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/home/vagrant/fullcast_project/producer/views/views.py" in post
  1141.                 autogenerate_click_to_tweet_if_needed(tweet)

File "/home/vagrant/fullcast_project/producer/helpers/__init__.py" in autogenerate_click_to_tweet_if_needed
  63.     meets_criteria = production.status() == 'Published'

Exception Type: AttributeError at /episodeclicktotweet/2/
Exception Value: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'status'
```

I have this form where I have a field where the user can input his tweet text and submit it. It will go into the DB but thats it. The thing though is that I want to have an additional button where it can generate the click to tweet link and an additional field where it will display the link that just created.

This is what I am trying implement to generate the link in my `views.py`:

```
if not tweet_ctt_link:
   autogenerate_click_to_tweet_if_needed(tweet)
   ProductionTweet.click_to_tweet_link(self)
   ProductionTweet.click_to_tweet_link = tweet_ctt_link
   tweet_ctt_link.save()
```

In my *helpers* folder, I have in my `__init__.py` the following method that will autogenerate the link:

```
def autogenerate_click_to_tweet_if_needed(production):
    """
    # We check if the click to tweet associated with this production
    # needs to be auto-generated. We only do this if it is NULL or empty
    # so that if user entered it manually it prevales.
    :param production:
    """
    if not production:
        return

    # 1. We check if the production meets the requirements for a click to tweet.
    #    If it does not we delete all click to tweet associated with the production.
    #    Criteria is to be Published.
    meets_criteria = production.status() == 'Published'
    if not meets_criteria:
        ClickToTweetProductionTweet.objects.filter(production=production).delete()
        return

    # 2. We get the first and only click to tweet for this production.
    click_to_tweet = ClickToTweetProductionTweet.objects.filter(production=production).first()
    # If we have a valid text in the tweet, we just return as we will not
    # modify an existing one.
    if click_to_tweet and click_to_tweet.tweet:
        return

    # 3. We get the format for the tweet from the Podcast.
    #    if we have no valid format then do nothing
    tweet_format = production.podcast.podcast_click_to_tweet_format
    if not tweet_format:
        return

    # 4. If we do not have a click to tweet we create one.
    if not click_to_tweet:
        click_to_tweet = ClickToTweetProductionTweet(production=production)

    # 5. We will make the necessary an possible substitutions on the format
    #    to compose the tweet text.
    #    Valid placeholders are:
    #    PODCAST_TWITTER_NAME = podcast_twitter_name (in podcast)
    #    PODCAST_GUEST_TWITTER_NAME = podcast_guest_twitter_name (in podcast)
    #    WORDPRESS_URL = wordpress_url (in production)
    tweet_format = replace_placeholder_in_text_format_with_parameter(tweet_format, 'PODCAST_TWITTER_NAME',
                                                                      production.podcast.podcast_twitter_name)
    tweet_format = replace_placeholder_in_text_format_with_parameter(tweet_format, 'PODCAST_GUEST_TWITTER_NAME',
                                                                      production.podcast.podcast_guest_twitter_name)
    wordpress_url = production.wordpress_short_url if production.wordpress_short_url else production.wordpress_url
    tweet_format = replace_placeholder_in_text_format_with_parameter(tweet_format, 'WORDPRESS_URL', wordpress_url)
    tweet_format = smart_text(tweet_format)

    # 6. Update and save
    click_to_tweet.tweet = tweet_format
    click_to_tweet.save()
```

Under my `ProductionTweet` class in `models.py`, I have the following method where I can grab the link:

```
def click_to_tweet_link(self):
        base_url = settings.CLICK_TO_TWEET_BASE_URL
        if not base_url:
            return None
        return base_url + self.slug
```

Here is the view for the tweet section in `views.py`:

```
class EpisodeClickToTweet(ProductionRequiredMixin, View):
form_class = EpisodeClickToTweetForm
template_name = 'fc/forms_clicktotweet.html'

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    initial_values = {}
    # See if we already have a click to tweet for this production, if so get id
    click_to_tweet = ClickToTweetProductionTweet.objects.filter(production_id=self.production.id).first()

    initial_values['production_id'] = self.production.id
    initial_values['id'] = click_to_tweet.id if click_to_tweet else None
    initial_values['tweet'] = click_to_tweet.tweet if click_to_tweet else None

    form = self.form_class(initial=initial_values)
    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    form = self.form_class(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        # lets get the data
        production_id = form.cleaned_data.get('production_id')
        id = form.cleaned_data.get('id')
        tweet = form.cleaned_data.get('tweet')
        tweet_ctt_link = form.cleaned_data.get('tweet_ctt_link')

        #A production must exist, othewise 404
        production = get_object_or_404(Production, id=production_id)

        if id:
            click_to_tweet = ClickToTweetProductionTweet.objects.get(id=id)
        else:
            click_to_tweet = ClickToTweetProductionTweet(production=production)

        click_to_tweet.tweet = tweet
        click_to_tweet.save()

        if not tweet_ctt_link:
            autogenerate_click_to_tweet_if_needed(tweet)
            ProductionTweet.click_to_tweet_link(self)
            ProductionTweet.click_to_tweet_link = tweet_ctt_link
            tweet_ctt_link.save()


        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('fc:episodeschedule', kwargs={'production_id':production_id}))

    return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})
```

Form for `ClickToTweet`:

```
from django import forms

import django

if django.VERSION < (1,7):
    from charsleft_widget.fields import CharField
else:
    from django.forms.fields import CharField

from charsleft_widget import CharsLeftArea

class EpisodeClickToTweetForm(forms.Form):
    production_id = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.Field.hidden_widget, required=False)
    id = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.Field.hidden_widget, required=False)
    tweet = forms.CharField(max_length=120, required=False,
                            widget=CharsLeftArea)
    tweet_ctt_link = forms.CharField(label='Click To Tweet Link', required=False,
                            widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Click To Tweet link will be generated here',}))
```

And template:

```
{% extends "fc/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}

<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped progress-bar-success active" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="87.5" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 87.5%">
    <span class="sr-only">87.5% Complete</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="panel panel-default box-shadow--16dp col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
<div class="panel-body">

<div class='row'>
<div class='col-sm-12'>

<h3>Setup | Add Episode</h3>

<h4>Twitter - Guest Click-To-Tweet</h4>

<h5>FC will also build the ‘clickable tweet’ which will be automatically sent in the body of the mail to your guest on the morning of the episode goes live.</h5>

<hr/>

<form method='POST' action=''>{% csrf_token %}
{{ form|crispy }}
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info box-shadow--6dp"><i class="fa fa-link" aria-hidden="true"></i> Generate Link
</button>

<hr/>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary box-shadow--6dp"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right pull-right"></i> Continue
</button>

</form>

</form>
</div>
</div>

</div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

**Any help or suggestions would be appreciated**

**------------ UPDATE -----------**

```
class Production(TimeStampedModel):
    BASE_PRODUCTION = 'B'
    SECONDARY_PRODUCTION = 'S'

    podcast = models.ForeignKey(Podcast, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    ready_for_production = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    episode_number = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    episode_title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    episode_guest_last_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True, blank=True)
    episode_guest_first_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True, blank=True)
    episode_guest_twitter_name = models.CharField(max_length=64, null=True, blank=True)
    episode_summary = models.TextField(blank=False, null=True)

    base_production_uuid = models.CharField(max_length=32, null=True, blank=True)
    base_production_status = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    base_production_produced = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    base_production_started = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    base_production_cover_image = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    square_image_file = models.ImageField(upload_to='square_image', null=True, blank=True)

    secondary_production_uuid = models.CharField(max_length=32, null=True, blank=True)
    secondary_production_status = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    secondary_production_produced = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    secondary_production_started = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    secondary_production_cover_image = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    banner_image_file = models.ImageField(upload_to='banner_image', null=True, blank=True)

    auphonic_result_url = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)
    soundcloud_result_url = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)
    soundcloud_error_message = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    youtube_result_url = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)
    youtube_error_message = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    libsyn_result_url = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)
    libsyn_error_message = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    spreaker_result_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    spreaker_result_id_request_attempted = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    source_file_name = models.CharField(max_length=64, null=True)
    source_file = models.FileField(upload_to='audio_source', null=True, blank=True)
    output_base_name = models.CharField(max_length=64, null=True)

    scheduled_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    time_scheduled = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)
    fully_produced_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    auto_email_sent = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    post_to_wordpress = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    wordpress_post_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    wordpress_slug = models.CharField(max_length=127, null=True, blank=True)
    wordpress_url = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)
    wordpress_short_url = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)
    wordpress_featured_image = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    wordpress_featured_image_upload = models.FileField(upload_to='wordpress_image', null=True, blank=True)
    wordpress_post_unique_tags = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    wordpress_posting_failure_notified = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    transcription_url = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)

    tweets_already_scheduled = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    number_of_refresh_tweets = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    tweets_scheduling_failure_notified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_podfunnel = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    asynch_publish_in_process = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return smart_text(self.base_production_episode_title())

    def fully_produced(self):
        return self.base_production_produced and self.secondary_production_produced
    fully_produced.short_description = 'Produced'

    def status(self):
        if not self.fully_produced():
            return 'Pending'
        if self.wordpress_url:
            return 'Published'
        return 'Produced'

    def base_status(self):
        if not self.base_production_produced:
            return 'Pending'
        if self.wordpress_url:
            return 'Published'
        return 'Produced'

    def episode(self):
        return self.episode_number

    def base_production_episode_title(self):
        return self._title_string_for_format(self.podcast.base_production_name_format)

    def secondary_production_episode_title(self):
        return self._title_string_for_format(self.podcast.secondary_production_name_format)

    def _title_string_for_format(self, title_format):
        from producer.helpers import replace_placeholder_in_text_format_with_parameter

        guest_name = self.episode_guest()
        episode_number = str(self.episode_number).zfill(3)
        episode_title = self.episode_title

        title = replace_placeholder_in_text_format_with_parameter(title_format, 'EPISODE_GUEST_FULL_NAME', guest_name)
        title = replace_placeholder_in_text_format_with_parameter(title, 'EPISODE_NUMBER', episode_number)
        title = replace_placeholder_in_text_format_with_parameter(title, 'EPISODE_TITLE', episode_title)

        return title

    def episode_guest(self):
        if self.episode_guest_last_name and self.episode_guest_first_name:
            return '%s %s' % (self.episode_guest_first_name, self.episode_guest_last_name)

        if self.episode_guest_last_name:
            return self.episode_guest_last_name

        if self.episode_guest_first_name:
            return self.episode_guest_first_name

        return ''

    def soundcloud_result_link(self):
        if self.soundcloud_result_url:
            return '<a href="%s" target="_blank">%s</a>' % (self.soundcloud_result_url, self.soundcloud_result_url)
        return
    soundcloud_result_link.allow_tags = True

    def auphonic_result_link(self):
        if self.auphonic_result_url:
            return '<a href="%s" target="_blank">%s</a>' % (self.auphonic_result_url, self.auphonic_result_url)
        return
    auphonic_result_link.allow_tags = True

    def youtube_result_link(self):
        if self.youtube_result_url:
            return '<a href="%s" target="_blank">%s</a>' % (self.youtube_result_url, self.youtube_result_url)
        return
    youtube_result_link.allow_tags = True

    def wordpress_link(self):
        if self.wordpress_url:
            return '<a href="%s" target="_blank">%s</a>' % (self.wordpress_url, self.wordpress_url)
        return
    wordpress_link.allow_tags = True

    def wordpress_short_link(self):
        if self.wordpress_short_url:
            return '<a href="%s" target="_blank">%s</a>' % (self.wordpress_short_url, self.wordpress_short_url)
        return
    wordpress_short_link.allow_tags = True

    def libsyn_result_link(self):
        if self.libsyn_result_url:
            return '<a href="%s" target="_blank">%s</a>' % (self.libsyn_result_url, self.libsyn_result_url)
        return
    libsyn_result_link.allow_tags = True

    def transcription_link(self):
        if self.transcription_url:
            return '<a href="%s" target="_blank">%s</a>' % (self.transcription_url, self.transcription_url)
        return
    transcription_link.allow_tags = True
```

Comment: Do you have a `production` class?

Comment: Updated my question with the `Production` class in the bottom from `models.py`. Thanks!

Comment: Does production need to be upper case?

Answer (score 0):

The `tweet` field in your form is a CharField. The value entered in that field is a string. But you send that value to your autogenerate helper, where you try to call `status()` on it.

It seems that you meant to send a Production instance to that helper instead.

Comment: Thanks for the help, so what would be the best approach to send that value to the helper so it can generate the link and send it back to `tweet_ctt_link` field?

Comment: I have no idea, there's so much code here it's impossible to tell what you are trying to do. But for a start you have a `production` variable there; maybe you meant to send that instead of `tweet`? And if you want to "send back" a value from the helper, you need to return it.